# How to handle high load of traffic of my server

Tags: performance

Soon, my website will have much traffic due to an event, is there anyway or any service that will help me to handle all the traffic without my website goes down?

I'm using WordPress running on Nginx with W3 Total Cache 0.9.2.11 and cloudflare.

Comment: Don't know why this would be migrated from serverfault, but, are you running a dedicated server, virtual private server or are you using shared hosting?  I'm assuming one of the first two, but the short answer is upgrade your server.  Add more ram, get a solid state hard drive instead of a "regular" one, get a better or more processors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about budget?

- I think you need add more RAM.
- Using Xcache or memcached.
- Using s3 amazon for your static file.

For more information ask in serverfault.